# How to run a github action on all descendents of a branch

Tags: github, yaml, branch, github-actions

I have a branch nested a few branches down and my GitHub actions don't seem to run on it.

```
o - develop (parent) [Runs fine]
\ _ branch-1 (child) [Runs fine]
    \ _ branch-2 (grand child) [Doesn't run]
       \ _ branch-3 (great grandchild) [Doesn't run]
```

After reviewing the github actions docs I still can't figure it out even though I'm sure my additions should work. However currently the action only runs on Develop or a direct descendent of develop, i.e a child but not a grandchild or great grandchild.

Below is the current 'on' chunk in my yml. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [develop, 'develop/**']
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop, 'develop/**']
```

Comment: Does every branch have the workflow file?

Comment: @riQQ yes it should do

Comment: What are the actual names of the child branches? Do their names contain `develop/`?

Comment: @riQQ, they do not the branch chain would be something like
develop ->  (240)-IssueName1 -> (132)-IssueName2 -> (304)-IssueName3